# Caroufredsel issue: not working properly to both sides, only working "to the left"

Tags: jquery, caroufredsel

I'm not using anything but Jquery and Caroufredsel. I'm working with Wordpress generated entries.

It works fine when it goes to the left, but when it auto-scrolls to the right or when I click the right pagination it goes completely nuts.

The live exemple is here:
http://apolinariopassos.com.br/nutricao/

The code is:
header.php

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/carouFredSel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#carrossel_home_pg').carouFredSel({
    prev: {
        key: "left"
    },
    next: {
        key: "right"
    },
    pagination: "#texto-slider-paginacao"
    });
});
</script>
```

index.php

```
<div id="carrossel_home_pg">
                    <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'post', 'cat' => '8', 'posts_per_page' => '3', 'category_name' => 'slider-home')); 
                          while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
                    ?>
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>   

                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </div>
                <div id="texto-slider-paginacao" class="pagination"></div>
```

The generated code is on the live exemple.

Thank in advance.

Comment: I turned on the debug mode and got "carouFredSel: Not a valid number of visible items: Set to "variable"."

Comment: João, you would be welcome in the br.stackoverflow.com, maybe you know it exists already...

Comment: You need a invitation, if you contact me offline with your mail, i send you a invitation (vou apagar estes comentários quando tiver lido isto)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error in my javascript, however I am using node.js rather than php...

I had to add a timeout when the carouFredSel function is called instead of having it run on $(document).Ready .  You could try something like the following inside your $(document).ready function:

```
function spec(){
    $('#carrossel_home_pg').carouFredSel({
    prev: {
        key: "left"
    },
    next: {
        key: "right"
    },
    pagination: "#texto-slider-paginacao"
    });
}
$(window).load(function() {
    setTimeout(spec(), 100);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the reason of this error may be **display:none** of carousel container. So this can be fixed by initializing plugin after wrapper became **display:block**.